# What's the most efficient way to exclude possible results from an SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have a subscription database containing Customers, Subscriptions and Publications tables.

The Subscriptions table contains ALL subscription records and each record has three flags to mark the status: isActive, isExpire and isPending. These are Booleans and only one flag can be True - this is handled by the application.

I need to identify all customers who have not renewed any magazines to which they have previously subscribed and I'm not sure that I've written the most efficient SQL query. If I find a lapsed subscription I need to ignore it if they already have an active or pending subscription for that particular magazine.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.id, Subscriptions.publicationName
FROM Subscriptions
LEFT JOIN Customers
ON Subscriptions.id_Customer = Customers.id
LEFT JOIN Publications
ON Subscriptions.id_Publication = Publications.id
WHERE Subscriptions.isExpired = 1
AND NOT EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM Subscriptions s2
WHERE s2.id_Publication = Subscriptions.id_Publication
AND s2.id_Customer = Subscriptions.id_Customer
AND s2.isPending = 1 )
AND NOT EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM Subscriptions s3
WHERE s3.id_Publication = Subscriptions.id_Publication
AND s3.id_Customer = Subscriptions.id_Customer
AND s3.isActive = 1 )
```

I have just over 50,000 subscription records and this query takes almost an hour to run which tells me that there's a lot of looping or something going on where for each record the SQL engine is having to search again to find any 'isPending' and 'isActive' records.

This is my first post so please be gentle if I've missed out any information in my question :) Thanks.

Comment: What hardware is it being run on?

Comment: In your DB, I presume that each row in the subscriptions table is one 'renewal' of one 'subscription' is that correct?  What I mean by this is that suppose a customer has a magazine and the sub expires Dec. 2015.  When he renews the subscription, does it create a new row in the subscriptions table, or does it simply flip the status back to active?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials 64-bit
Intel Xeon CPU E3-1220 v3 @ 3.10Ghz
4Gb RAM

Comment: Nate M. - yes, you are correct, I create a new row so that we can analyse historical data. If I change the status of an existing subscription then we lose that ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your complete database structure, so I can't test the following query but it may contain some optimization.  I will leave it to you to test, but will explain why I have changed, what I have changed.

```
select Distinct Customers.id, Subscriptions.publicationName 
from Subscriptions 
join Customers on Subscriptions.id_Customer = Customer.id
join Publications
ON Subscriptions.id_Publication = Publications.id
Where Subscriptions.isExpired = 1
And Not Exists
(select * from Subscriptions s2
join Customers on s2.id_Customer = Customer.id
join Publications
ON s2.id_Publication = Publications.id
where s2.id_Customer = s2.id_customer and 
(s2.isPending = 1 or s2.isActive = 1))
```

If you have no resulting data in Customer or Publications DB, then the Subscription information isn't useful, so I eliminated the LEFT join in favor of simply join.  Combine the two Exists subqueries.  These are pretty intensive if I recall so the fewer the better.  Last thing which I did not list above but may be worth looking into is, can you run a subquery with specific data fields returned and use it in an Exists clause?  The use of Select * will return all data fields which slows down processing.  I'm not sure if you can limit your result unfortunately, because I don't have an equivalent DB available to me that I can test on (the google probably knows).

I suspect there are further optimizations that could be made on this query.  Eliminating the Exists clause in favor of an 'IN' clause may help, but I can't think of a way right now, seeing how you've got to match two unique fields (customer id and the relevant subscription).  Let me know if this helps at all.

With a table of 50k rows, you should be able to run a query like this in seconds.

Comment: Thanks so much. Using the 'OR' to combine the 'isPending = 1' and 'isActive =1' has made a real improvement. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Glad to have helped!